# Редирект в Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Здравствуйте.
Мне нужно осуществить редирект в фреймворке Code Igniter (редирект на класс, вида: www.site.ru -> www.site.ru/myclass/ ), при этом не задавая класс по умолчанию и не используя редирект htaccess (из-за специфичности фреймворка он создает бесконечный цикл). Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Редирект чего куда ? Почему бесконечный цикл (я что-то такого не припомню)? какая разница, кто пошлет заголовок ? Главное - назначение редиректа. не задавая класс - вначале index.php :) Если же вы про  rewrite - конфигурируйте роутер.

Comment: т.е. редиректит на www.site.ru/myclass/myclass/myclass/myclass...

Comment: вы про routes.php? Если да, то я сказал, что вот именно нельзя по умолчанию класс задавать)

Comment: пример давайте, иначе мне видится ваша проблема надуманной.